# Prevent selection while scrolling with mouse in devexpress comobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, scroll, devexpress, mousewheel

I have a combobox as a treelist element. Combobox popup is done and item is selected. But in between if mouse is scrolled selection changes. I want to disable it. Only mouse click is permitted and mouse scroll not allowed. I tried

AllowMouseWheel = false.    // It didnt work.

Then handled MouseWheel eventHandler. **Given focus to combobox**. Then wrote the following code

cboAccount.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(cboAccount_MouseWheel);
and set

Dim Hme As HandledMouseEventArgs = e
Hme.Handled = True

in cboAccount_MouseWheel().

But mousewheel event is not firing. I put breakpoint its not hitting.

Please suggest ways to fix the issue.

Comment: Handle Closed event and set form's ActiveControl to something else.

Comment: Have you looked at the DevExpress support center? https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t507640/how-to-prevent-a-lookupedit-comboboxedit-from-scrolling-with-the-mouse-wheel/

Comment: I went through that link earlier itself. But it was not clear for me.

Comment: This issue is not fixed even now.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may work.
In a common combobox you can use this:

```
ComboBox.Properties.AllowMouseWheel = False
```